# parsing html tag in python with reg not working

Tags: python, html-parsing

im having a bit of trouble with this code as it is not working how i intend it. i know regular expressions arent the best way to fo this but i couldnt figure out how to do it with the html parser and beautiful soup isnt an option. heres what im trying to do. i have an html file and i need to extract the value between

```
<div class="e_mail"> and </div>
```

when i use the below code however it returns the email address as such:

```
['returned@email.com']
```

how can i get the email address without the brackets and quotes? id rather use something cleaner than reg but as i said couldnt figure out the html parser.

```
f=urllib.urlopen('results.html')
s = str(f.read())
return re.compile('<div class="e_mail">(.*?)</div>', re.DOTALL).findall(s)
```

Comment: that worked great. i was trying to do that but was going about it all wrong. i know RE isnt the way to do this but i don't really need anything better. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
return re.compile(expr, re.DOTALL).findall(s)[0]
```

Alternatively:

```
return re.findall(r'<div class="e_mail">(.*?)</div>', s, re.DOTALL)[0]
```

Note that if there are no results, you'll get an `IndexError` because `re.findall` will simply return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

```
f=urllib.urlopen('results.html')
s = str(f.read())
email = re.compile('<div class="e_mail">(.*?)</div>', re.DOTALL).findall(s)
return email[0]
```

Also make sure it is not an empty list before returning it.